# Code after showDialog is not execute when the modal window is closed by the other thread -- C#

Tags: c#, window, modal-dialog, showdialog

In my program, I need to pop up the modal window prompt user to do some operations, the modal windows close automatically once user finish the operation.

in one thread, the code will be blocked at `ShowDialog()` and the code after it cannot be executed. 
the Main source code like this:

```
MyMessageBox myMsgBox = null

private void UserInputRead()
{
  myMsgBox = new MyMessageBox(); //customerized messageBox extends from Form
  //some operation
  Thread t1 = new Thread(UserInputListener);
  t1.start();
  myMsgBox.ShowDialog();
  Console.WriteLine("...after showDialog()");
}
```

in the other thread, it monitor the user input, if meet requirement then dispose the modal dialog.

```
private void UserInputListerner()
{
  //monitor user input 
  if(xxx) //user input meet the requirement
  {
     myMsgBox.Dispose()
  }
}
```

when the user input meet requirement, the modal dialog has been disposed, but the code after `ShowDialog()` still can not be executed, but when I tried to use the Timer or `KeyEventHandler` to dispose this modal dialog, the code after `ShowDialog()` can be executed.

The requirement is to automatically close the modal window when the user finish some operations and some other handling after close the modal window.

Any ideal how to resolved it and implement this requirement? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try

```
myMsgBox.Close() 

or

myMsgBox.Hide()
```

it may help

Comment: Really appreciate your help, i tried your proposal, the modal window disappeared and the code after ShowDialog() can be executed. but i still wonder why the program blocked when call disposed method, could you tell me the reason?

Comment: When you use "myMsgBox.Dispose()" it dispose the myMsgBox object from memory and does not return on that location from where it has called.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but why if i use "myMsgBox.Dispose()" at the 'Timer' or 'keyEventHandler' of the Form, the program will be not block and the code after ShowDialog() can be executed?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a long running or slow operation, there is no reason why you should complicate your life with a separate thread. Just show your dialog form in modal mode and proceed when the user has input the required data.